# How to pass username into login SQL codes of application.properties on Spring Boot security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I try to make simple login codes with spring boot security. First, this is the application.properties codes which includes login query.

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=FALSE

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?characterEncoding=utf8&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.queries.users-query=select user_name, password_hash, id from users where user_name=?
spring.queries.roles-query=select user_name, 'ADMIN' AS 'role' from users where user_name=?
```

And Below codes are about spring boot login security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Value("{spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("{spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery).authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
            .dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }
```

The problem is I have no idea how to transfer user_name value into spring.queries.users-query statement of application.properties file. I execute this spring boot security codes without any modification, but the exception is thrown like this,

```
2018-12-15 16:03:00.821 ERROR 2284 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.    

Caused by: org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [{spring.queries.users-query}]; Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:110) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1402) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:620) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:657) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:688) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:751) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUsersByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:227) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUserByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:184) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:104) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        ... 57 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3367) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setInternal(PreparedStatement.java:3352) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setString(PreparedStatement.java:4068) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setString(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:400) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:232) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:163) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:69) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:50) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:664) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        ... 64 common frames omitted
```

How can I pass the user_name value into the login SQL statement of Spring security configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with the @Value annotation. It should be used as `@Value("${<property}")`, Spring boot won't bind the value without proper usage.

```
@Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
private String usersQuery;

@Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
private String rolesQuery;
```

You don't need to pass/append username value here. [usersByUsernameQuery()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/provisioning/JdbcUserDetailsManagerConfigurer.html#usersByUsernameQuery-java.lang.String-) is to set the query explicitly.